# Flutter: don't see page completely

Tags: flutter

I am page like this photo in flutter: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yCAR.jpg)

how could i fix this error?
I need to see page completely.

just want to see page with all components.

when I add another widget always did not dload all page with all widgets.

my code is like here:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: myMobileAppBar(false),
  body: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 10, 15),
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    decoration: myDecoration,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        const MyLableObligatori(
          inputtext: 'Codice Prodotto:',
        ),
        Row(
          //Mycode
        ),
        const MyLable(inputtext: 'Codice Fattura:'),
        const MyTextField(),
        const MyLable(inputtext: 'Descrizione:'),
        const MyTextField(maxsize: 5),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        //Categoria List
        //const CategoriaList(),
        PrintCatList(categoriaDataSource),

        Row(
          //Mycode
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        const MyLableObligatori(inputtext: 'Nome Fornitore:'),
        DropdownButton(items: null, onChanged: null),
        Align(
            //Mycode
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your content isn't scrollable and the widgets take more space than your screen height.Therefore your body gets overflowed. Try one of the  following properties.

1.Add following to your **Scaffold**:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true
```

2.Wrap your widget in **SingleChildScrollView**

```
    SingleChildScrollView(
  child: ColumnName(),
  )
```

Comment: I added my code with edit post.

Comment: i did two things that you said, but does not work.

Comment: return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: myMobileAppBar(false),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 10, 15),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          decoration: myDecoration,
          child: Column(
           
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wrap your column widget inside the singlechildscrollview. And also you have to manage all things inside the column ,have a fixed height or wrap with expanded or flexible.

Comment: I added my code with edit post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Singlechildscrollview inside Column with Fixed Height and Adjust it properly by giving static/dynamic height in the app.

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (_, constraints) {
    double viewSize= constraints.maxHeight;
    if (viewSize > minSize) return child;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: viewSize, maxWidth: isHz ? minSize : //width here),
        child: // Your widgets here.,
      ),
    )
```

Comment: I added my code with edit post.

Comment: wrap scaffold with the child here.